# Tener un onClick de un elemento desactivado

Tags: java, android

tengo un `textview` desactivado.

```
campoTv.setEnabled(false);
```

y busco enviar un mensaje (toast u otro similar) con un mensaje diciendo que esta desactivado.... cuando se le de clic. Pero cuando uso `setEnabled(false)` no puedo acceder a mi `setOnItemClickListener`

¿como puedo lograrlo?

EDITO:
Acabo de probar con un setOnTouchListener sin exito, tampoco entra en él si uso `setEnabled(false)`

Comment: si desactivas la vista no se podría configurar un listener a esta, debes revisar otra opción!

Answer (score 2):

Cambia el estilo, cuando lo desactives, en vez de llamar el setEnabled, cámbiale el estilo del botón para que se vea desactivado, y en el onclick verificas si esta activado o no

Comment: gracias, voy a probar eso

Answer (score 2):

Si deshabilitas una vista mediante el método o propiedad :

```
setEnabled(false)
```

**No hay forma de configurar un listener.**

Comment: ok gracias, ahora estoy poniendo un LinearLayout invisible sobre el campo que hará de listener